# Changes done on EC2 instance took effect after restarting the server

Tags: apache-2.2, php, amazon-ec2, svn

I'm working on a website that i built with codeigniter framework. I'm using amazon EC2 instance since last 1 month.

Today while doing some work i found that changes done in PHP files are not reflecting on live site. First i thought it must be an issue with SVN and files may not be going on the server when i commit them or going late.

So i access the EC2 instance with SSH and check some files with vi editor. Changes were actually there. I got very confuse so put a echo "Test" and die() in the opening of the function right there. It did not work. Then i try the echo and die statements in constructor of this controller. It also did not work. Then i try another controller and same result. I even put a wall of garbage text between the PHP code to produce a syntax error but nothing happens. When i opened the website in browser only 1-2 hour old functionality was working. No recent changes were reflecting.

In the end, i restarted the instance from amazon console and voila !!! It worked, all the changes are now reflects on live.

I want to know what might have caused this, so that it does not turn out a problem for me in the future.

Comment: Do you have an opcode cache or PHP accelerator sort of thing in place?

Comment: @ceejayoz, No, its very basic server setup just PHP, mysql and apache2 on ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: Not really sure, but some PHP 5.5+ distributions (depending on your repos) embed and enable the PHP Opcache package by default.

Comment: @ma.tome, you are right. I just check and opcache is already embed and enable by default (Zend OPcache v7.0.3).